# How to call a Java class from a Android Activity

Tags: java, android

I have an Android activity called main.java and BPMClass.java class.  I need to call the BPMClass.java within the main.java class.  I wrote the code in the following way (does not show function name):

```
import com.app.BPMClass;
... 
public class main extends Activity {
BPMClass bpmclass;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    bpmclass = new BPMClass("filename");
    bpmclass.    // does not show the function name of BPMClass.
  }
}

....
BPMClass{
   String fname;
   public BPMClass(String filename){
    fname=filename
   }
  public int fun1(fname){
   int val=0;
    .......
  return val; 
 }
}
```

Comment: check wether you have saved that class properly or not, or have you editor setup for build is automatically or not

Comment: Just guessing, the signature of `BPMClass` is incomplete in this post and really reads `public class BPMClass`

Comment: Editing with eclipse? Automatic build switched on? Code completion shows `BPMClass` constructor but not public method `fun1`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `BPMClass` is declared as public, then code is fine.

Comment: My answer were earlier posted.

Answer (score 6):

Declared access modifier of class as according to your need, if class needed to access from its package level, then this should work fine.. else declare it as public

Answer (score 0):

problem is simple if he try to place class after name of the class

```
   class BPMClass{
   String fname;
   public BPMClass(String filename){
    fname=filename
   }
  public int fun1(fname){
   int val=0;
    .......
  return val; 
 }
}
```